# setBackground on custom RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout

All,

I've got a custom `RelativeLayout` and after the view loads, I'd like to change the background of the `RelativeLayout` to a drawable. I can't figure out why the heck it's not working...seems like it should be so simple.

Here is my code for my custom layout:

```
public class InputBoxView extends RelativeLayout {

    //My variables

    //Irrelevants initalizers

    //Method in question
    public void addErrorBox() {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error_border);
    }

}
```

Here is the layout file for the custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_line_height"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <View
        style="@style/space_view"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/input_box_textview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Key" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_box_edittext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        style="@style/space_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my `error_border`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/red"/>
</shape>
```

When I call the `addErrorBox` method from my activity, my background doesn't **visibly** change, but if I put a breakpoint on the instance of the `InputBoxView`, the `mBackground` property changes after I call the `addErrorBox`, so the background I believe is changing, but not updating.

I tried calling `invalidate()` on the instance of the `InputBoxView`, but it still didn't work.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I tested with the code you gave, the issue is the

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

on the relative layout for the custom view xml. It seems to neglect whatever you set with `setBackgroundResource` for `InputBoxView`.

Once I removed that attribute, I was able to see the red border background.

One solution to this is to remove the `RelativeLayout` from the xml since your `InputBoxView` already extends from it and set the white background, width height and what not when you inflate your custom view.

So your xml can look something like this

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <!-- Your views in here without the RelativeLayout -->
</merge>
```

and in your `InputBoxView`

```
public InputBoxView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_custom, this, true);

    // Set what you need for the relative layout.
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

}

public void addErrorBox() {
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.error_border);
    invalidate();
}
```

Or you can add an ID to the RelativeLayout and modify the background directly instead of on the `InputBoxView`.

And for [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29), you'll need it after onCreate so that it is redrawn.

Hope that helps resolve your issue or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is insane. Shouldn't it be a bug?